# Need assistance with point of sale application

Tags: android

I am developing a point of sale application and i have been tasked to have a home activity that displays statistics about the businesses perfomance using a bar some for of diagram(pie or barchart). I have no idea of how to do it.

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Start by googling "android bar chart" or something like that.  That should give you some ideas about where to start.

Comment: thanks will do that asap

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [MPAndroid Chart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), it has pie charts and bar charts, so everything you need and it has a good documentation on github.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of bar chart using mp android charts:

https://www.android-examples.com/create-bar-chart-graph-using-mpandroidchart-library/

Following are examples of pie chart with mp android charts:

https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-pie-chart-using-mpandroidchart-library-tutorial/

http://androidbuddys.com/pie-chartdonut-chart-using-mp-chart/

https://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-create-a-pie-chart-in-android-with-mpandroidchart/

I used these examples to create my charts. This will work like a charm.

Comment: Dont forget to mark this post as answer if it helped you :) Happy coding bro :)